# Why is my Sony Vegas Pro created *.avi file not 'prepared for sequential reading'?

Tags: video, encoding, avi, sony-vegas

The issue at hand:

[image]

Although I can play the resulting encoded .avi file by any media player, I'd like to know WHAT am I doing wrong?

Here's what my options look like before encoding starts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You definitely must set Interleave options. (At greenshot_2010-04-11_0lzpo.png.)
I dont know optimal interleave for you case, Search and experiment from every frame to some seconds. Prefer multiply the number of frames.
every frame = 1/29.97fps = 0.033s
every two frames = 0.067s
...

Lover values of interleaving is better for "sequential read" but
lower values of interleaving gives larger file size.

I  think, ideally, the size of the chunk must be equal the size of read block or size of readahead buffer.